# Should I use global variables in recursion

Tags: c, variables, recursion, global

I created a function in C to find the shortest path out of a triangle maze using recursion. I use 2 global variables in the function, which I want to get rid of because I know that global variables should not be used.

The variable `moves`, I could pass as an argument, but I don't know if it's bad memory management to overwhelm the stack like that.
The other global variable `foundExit` would not work as an argument, so I don't know how to get rid of it.

**So my question is whether I should use global variables in case of recursion.**

Note that every number in our array is some 3-bit number, where 1 represents wall and 0 empty wall. 001 is left wall, 010 is right wall, 100 is bottom/upper wall. So for example 111 represents triangle with all his walls.

Picture of our maze saved in cells:

[image: image of our maze]

Simplified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    unsigned char *cells;
} Map;

void NegateEntraceBit(Map *map, unsigned char r, unsigned char c) {
    char whichWall;
    if (c == 0) { // From left.
        whichWall = 0;
    }
    else if (c == map->cols - 1) { // From right.
        whichWall = 1;
    }
    else if (r == 0) { // From up.
        whichWall = 2;
    }
    else if (r == map->rows - 1) { // From down.
        whichWall = 2;
    }

    //Inverting entrace bit.
    map->cells[map->cols * r + c] ^= (1 << whichWall); 
}

char InvertDirection(char direction) {
    if (direction == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (direction == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

char moves[2][3][2] = {
    {{0,-1}, {0,1}, {-1,0}},
    {{0,-1}, {0,1}, {1,0}}
};

bool foundExit = false;

void shortestPath(Map map, int r, int c, char direction) {
/* 
         (r+c) % 2 == 1:        (r+c) % 2 == 0:
                ^               _________
              ╱   ╲             ╲   2   ╱
           0 ╱     ╲ 1         0 ╲     ╱ 1
            ╱_______╲             ╲   ╱
                2                   v
*/
    
    // Going in the direction if its the only way (triangle has value 0b100).
    while (map.cells[map.cols * r + c] == 3) {
        r += moves[(r+c) & 1][direction][0];
        c += moves[(r+c) & 1][direction][1];

        // This validating is performed when we go in 1 line to the exit.
        if (r < 0 || r >= map.rows || c < 0 || c >= map.cols) { // Outside position
            foundExit = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    // This validating is performed when a new instance is called.
    if (r < 0 || r >= map.rows || c < 0 || c >= map.cols) { // Outside position
        foundExit = true;
        return;
    }

    // This validating is performed when the only other way is in inverted direction.
    if ((map.cells[map.cols * r + c] ^ (1 << InvertDirection(direction))) == 0b111) {
        return;
    }

    printf("%d,%d\n", r+1, c+1);

    // For any other direction
    for (char direc = 0; direc < 3; direc++) {
        // that is (available && not in inverted direction),
        if ( !(map.cells[map.cols * r + c] & (1 << direc)) && (direc != InvertDirection(direction))) {
            // we call new instance with new coordinates.
            shortestPath(map,
                         r + moves[(r+c) & 1][direc][0], 
                         c + moves[(r+c) & 1][direc][1], 
                         direc);
        } 
        // Stopping any other instance that would be called even when the exit is found.
        if (foundExit) {
            break;
        }            
    }
}

int main() {
    Map map;
    map.rows = 6;
    map.cols = 7; // Set to the number of columns in your data

    // Allocate memory for 1D array
    map.cells = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (map.rows * map.cols));

    // Initialize the 1D array directly
    unsigned char initialData[] = {
        1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 0, 6,
        1, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 2,
        1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 6, 1,
        1, 2, 7, 1, 0, 4, 2,
        3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2,
        4, 2, 5, 0, 4, 2, 5
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < map.rows * map.cols; i++) {
        map.cells[i] = initialData[i];
    }
    int r = 6;
    int c = 1;

    int rows = r-1;
    int cols = c-1;

    // Closing entrace bit so its not the shortest path out.
    NegateEntraceBit(&map, rows, cols);
    //For every direction
    for (char direc = 0; direc < 3; direc++) {
        // That is available (0).
        if ( !(map.cells[map.cols * rows + cols] & (1 << direc)) ) {
            shortestPath(map, rows, cols, direc);
        }     
    }

    // Free allocated memory
    free(map.cells);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing you can do is to put the control variables in a `struct` and pass around a pointer to the `struct`.

Comment: Didn't check for given function, but if it can be [tail call optimised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) then you don't need to care for blowing up the stack, the stack frame of the previous call simply will be reused for next recursion.

Comment: @WeatherVane However if every recursion creates its own struct then we don't gain anything but an additional pointer...

Comment: @Aconcagua that's not what I suggested (although you might need distinct local variables), but to have a `struct` in the calling function for the variables which OP had as global. So if there were say 3 global variables, then you only need to pass one argument for them all and not 3. OP was asking how not to overwhelm the stack .

Comment: @demon OK, forget about tail call optimisation – the recursive call isn't necessarily the last thing you actually do… Seems to me as if the function could be modified such that it *is* suitable, though (if interested in: direction as additional parameter instead of for loop). In any case: `foundExit` can be dropped entirely in favour of a boolean return value of the function!

Comment: `moves` doesn't change. It's value is only used to help the calculation. So you can declare it `const` and not worry about it. Or you could declare it `static const` and put it inside the one function where it it used.

Comment: With boolean return value: Instead of `foundExit = true;` have `return true;` and where you return without setting the variable `return false;`; at the recursive call: `for(...) { if(shortestPath(...)) { return true; } } /* after the loop: you haven't found so far! */ return false;`

Comment: Note, too: Either variant, yours or mine (return value) doesn't necessarily find the shortest path, but the first one discovered via depths first search (if I read the code correctly at that short glance…). Finding the *shortest* path likely requires a breadth first search instead.

Comment: Why must your program be an illustration of all bad practices C offer at once? Can't you write it without _any_ bad practices? Recursion is several magnitudes worse practice than using global variables. It's one of those truly horrible things that should literally never be used except in some 0.001% special use case.

Comment: @Lundin What are you talking about? Recursion is coding 101 stuff, and can greatly simplify the logic in any number of situations. Why do you claim it's horrible?

Comment: @Ray Because it just as often makes the code _more_ complex. Because it more often than not leads to significantly slower code due to failed tail-call optimizations when programmers greatly overestimate the compiler's ability to turn their misguided recursion mess into tail-call and thereby possible to inline. Because it leads to a hard to predict stack peak usage which is a well-known hazard and a common cause for stack overflows. Because it overall leads to higher RAM consumption. To mention the drawbacks. Now you make the arguments why it is oh-so good - no subjective arguments, please.

Comment: @Lundin First, I'll agree that your arguments are legitimate issues (although I don't think they merit never using recursion). Please forgive me; I assumed you were making the (all too common) "I can't be bothered to learn this, so let's call it bad practice" argument and responded harshly. Reductions in code size and cyclomatic complexity are the main advantages that I see. In particular, any sort of graph traversal with backtracking is likely to be at least twice the size without recursion, and in many cases, requires manually building the stack mechanism that recursion gives you for free.

Comment: @Ray There is never a reduction in code size when using recursion, but often an increase - obviously more functions lead to increased code size. But even in case of tail-call optimization and inlining, since the inlined recursion will not necessarily result in a loop but could as well result in an unrolled loop and thereby creating increased code size. Cyclomatic complexity is never lower than a loop, but possibly higher since the recursion may need a separate exit condition in addition to the "loop" condition.

Comment: @Ray You may use recursion to trade separate `.data` space for stack space, but that doesn't mean that data used during recursion is allocated in thin air. You do get a temporary memory peak instead of a potentially constant size, in case a separate "stack like" ADT is used to keep track of the previous node during tree traversal etc. Although that can also be solved by integrating a `previous` pointer in the BST node itself, likely a speed over memory optimization.

Comment: Now another advantage of having your home-made stack ADT is that you actually have control over the size and the stack pointer can't run off into the woods screaming, as is very much possible during recursion.

Comment: *"There is never a reduction in code size when using recursion...Cyclomatic complexity is never lower than a loop."* Then write a smaller version of this that doesn't have more than two paths through the function: `void inorder(Tree_Node *node, void (*f)(Tree_Node*)) { if (node) { inorder(node->left, f); f(node); inorder(node->right, f); } }`. (You keep mentioning tail-calls, so I should clarify: I don't advocate replacing loops with recursion just because we can. I use recursion if and only if it simplifies the code. That's often not the case for code where tail-call elimination is possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both globals are accessed in a single function `shortestPath()` so they can be declared as `static` within that function.

```c
void shortestPath(Map map, int r, int c, char direction) 
{
    static char moves[2][3][2] = {
        {{0,-1}, {0,1}, {-1,0}},
        {{0,-1}, {0,1}, {1,0}}
    };

    static bool foundExit = false;

    ...
```

In other cases where a variable is shared amongst several functions, place all those functions and variables in a separately compiled source file and declare the variables and any functions that are not externally referenced `static` which in this case is a *linkage specifier* rather than *storage class specifier* as above, and restricts the scope to that translation unit (so no longer global).

Note that this is a general solution to the issue if global variables. It is not specific to recursion which is often also ill-advised. There are other techniques.  It is possible to write code of any size with no global variables at all, ever.

Answer (score 1):

My question was answered, so the solution was to mark the **moves** variable as **static**.

To remove the **foundExit** variable, I decided to make the return value a bool. The logic is basically the same.
As for the rest of the code, I changed it slightly, not keeping track of where I've been is extremely inefficient, so I created a new array **visited** where I just keep track of where I've been.

**NOTE:**
After more analysis, I found that this algorithm does not always find the shortest path. The algorithm has the best performance when the shortest path is clear, only other dead-end paths come from the shortest path.

Simplified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    unsigned char *cells;
} Map;

void NegateEntraceBit(Map *map, unsigned char r, unsigned char c) {
    char whichWall;
    if (c == 0) { // From left.
        whichWall = 0;
    }
    else if (c == map->cols - 1) { // From right.
        whichWall = 1;
    }
    else if (r == 0) { // From up.
        whichWall = 2;
    }
    else if (r == map->rows - 1){ // From down.
        whichWall = 2;
    }

    //Inverting entrace bit.
    map->cells[map->cols * r + c] ^= (1 << whichWall); 
}

char InvertDirection(char direction) {
    if (direction == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (direction == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

bool shortestPath(Map map, bool *visited, int r, int c, char direction) {
/* 
         (r+c) % 2 == 1:        (r+c) % 2 == 0:
                ^               _______________
              ╱   ╲             ╲      2      ╱
          0 ╱       ╲ 1         0 ╲         ╱ 1
          ╱           ╲             ╲     ╱
        ╱_______2_______╲              v
*/
    static char moves[2][3][2] = {
        {{0,-1}, {0,1}, {-1,0}},
        {{0,-1}, {0,1}, {1,0}}
    };

    r += moves[(r+c) & 1][direction][0];
    c += moves[(r+c) & 1][direction][1];

    if (visited[map.cols * r + c]) {
        return false;
    }
    
    visited[map.cols * r + c] = true;

    // This validating is performed when a new instance is called.
    if (r < 0 || r >= map.rows || c < 0 || c >= map.cols) { // Outside position
        return true;
    }

    // This validating is performed when the only other way is in inverted direction.
    if ((map.cells[map.cols * r + c] ^ (1 << InvertDirection(direction))) == 0b111) {
        return false;
    }

    // For any other direction
    for (char direc = 0; direc < 3; direc++) {
        // that is (available && not in inverted direction),
        if ( !(map.cells[map.cols * r + c] & (1 << direc)) && (direc != InvertDirection(direction)) ) {
            // we call new instance with wanted direction.
            if (shortestPath(map, visited, r, c, direc)) {
                printf("%d,%d\n", r+1, c+1 );
                return true;
            } 
        }         
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    Map map;
    map.rows = 6;
    map.cols = 7; // Set to the number of columns in your data

    // Allocate memory for 1D array
    map.cells = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (map.rows * map.cols));

    // Initialize the 1D array directly
    unsigned char initialData[] = {
        1,4,4,2,5,0,6,
        1,4,4,0,4,0,2,
        1,0,4,0,4,6,1,
        1,2,7,1,0,4,2,
        3,1,4,2,3,1,2,
        4,2,5,0,4,2,5
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < map.rows * map.cols; i++) {
        map.cells[i] = initialData[i];
    }

    bool *visited = (bool *)malloc((map.rows * map.cols) * sizeof(bool));
    for (int i = 0; i < map.rows * map.cols; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    int r = 6;
    int c = 1;

    int rows = r-1;
    int cols = c-1;

    // Closing entrace bit, so its not the shortest path out.
    NegateEntraceBit(&map, rows, cols);
    bool foundExit = false;
    /// For any other direction
    for (char direc = 0; direc < 3; direc++) {
        // that is (available && not in inverted direction),
        if ( !(map.cells[map.cols * rows + cols] & (1 << direc)) ) {
            //we call new instance with wanted direction.
            foundExit |= (shortestPath(map, visited, rows, cols, direc));
            printf("%d,%d\n", r, c);
        }     
    }
    if (!foundExit) {
        printf("There is no exit in maze.\n");
    } 
    
    // Free allocated memory
    free(visited);
    free(map.cells);

    return 0;
}
```